# Is Javax.ImageIO supported by graalVM native-image?

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am testing graalVM native image limitations with multiple different java features. I wrote a little program that performs canny edge detection and it loads in images using javax.ImageIO class. the code compiles to a native image just fine but I get the following runtime error when running code as a native image:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.initJPEGImageReader()J [symbol: Java_com_sun_imageio_plugins_jpeg_JPEGImageReader_initJPEGImageReader or Java_com_sun_imageio_plugins_jpeg_JPEGImageReader_initJPEGImageReader__]
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.access.JNINativeLinkage.getOrFindEntryPoint(JNINativeLinkage.java:145)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.nativeCallAddress(JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.java:57)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.initJPEGImageReader(JPEGImageReader.java)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.<init>(JPEGImageReader.java:232)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(JPEGImageReaderSpi.java:85)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(ImageReaderSpi.java:320)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:532)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:516)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1463)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1315)
    at Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

which is caused by the following line of code:

```
        File file = new File(args[0]);

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
```

I tried to specify JpegImageReader in my jni-config.json file:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true
  }
]
```

However i still get the same error as before. Does anyone know if ImageIO can be supported in graalvm native image and if it's not supporter why not?

Comment: PNG-files work. JPEGs don't.